# How do I have my jar re-deployed and put into docker image every time I run compose?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, kotlin, docker-compose

So I know that there are a lot of tutorials on the topics, both docker and maven, but I'm having some confusion in combining them alltogether.

I created a multi-module Maven project with 2 modules, 2 spring applications, let's call them application 1 and application 2.

Starting each other via IntelliJ IDEA green "run" button works fine, now I'd like to automate things and run via docker.

I have Dockerfiles that looks the same in both cases:
(in both modules it's the same, only JAR name's different)

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
MAINTAINER *my name here lol*
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/application1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
CMD /wait && /*.jar
```

I also have docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  application1:
    container_name: app1
    build:
      context: ../app1
    image: docker.io/myname/app1:latest
    hostname: app1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network-app1
  application2:
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: ../app2
    depends_on:
      application1:
        condition: service_started
    links:
      - application1
    image: docker.io/myname/app2:latest
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: application1:8080
    ports:
      - "8070:8070"
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network-app2
networks:
  spring-cloud-network-app1:
    driver: bridge
  spring-cloud-network-app2:
    driver: bridge
```

What I do currently is:

- I run maven package for each module and receive files like "application1(-2)-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" in both target folders.
- "docker build -t springio/app1 ."
- "docker-compose up --build"

And it works, but I feel I do some extra steps.
How can I do the project so that I ONLY have to run docker compose?
(after each time I change things in the code)

Again, I know it's a quite simple thing but I kinda lost the logic.

Thanks!

P.S
Ah, and about the "...docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait"
It's important that app start one after another, tried different solutions, unfortunately, doesn't really work as good as I would like to. But I guess I'll leave it as is.

Comment: What's the benefit of using Docker / Compose in this case? Why don't you just keep starting your applications from within the IDE (while actively developing)?

Comment: @slauth
Good question, basically I can call it "for the sake of knowing more in the field of webdev"

Comment: Well, you managed to get it working. But it's not exactly well-suited for interactive development I would say. What I sometimes use `docker-compose` for is to spin up some supportive services (like databases).

Comment: Btw, *"It's important that app start one after another"* – that's not a good thing, you could work on improving this situation.

Comment: _Well, you managed to get it working_
Indeed, but I have to recreate jar everytime, wonder how to do it automatically

Comment: What about a simple script then? Btw, you don't need to run the `docker build` command when you're also using the `--build` option.

Answer (score 0):

So, again, if anyone ever wonders how to do the things I asked, here's the answer: you need multi-stage build Dockerfile.
It'll look like this:

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/demo.jar"]
```

What it does is it basically first creates a jar file, copies it into package stage and eventually runs.
That's allow you to run your app in docker by running only docker compose.